# How to embed Azure Kusto Dashboard panel as iframe in Grafana Dashboard

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-data-explorer, grafana-dashboard

**Problem Statement:**

I've Grafana dashboard in **Grafana** and Kusto Dashboard in **Azure Kusto Data Explorer**.

And, I'm trying to integrate some panels of **Kusto** dashboard into **Grafana** dashboard using **Iframe** as I want to make only one dashboard for these.

**Tried Examples**

Well, I tried many examples which are similar to my problem but got no luck.

And, mostly, I'm getting examples like: Embed Grafana in website or some Angular, or ReactJs ., etc on Internet.

**Links of Tried Examples:**

https://www.itpanther.com/embedding-grafana-in-iframe/

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/share-panel/

[Embedding a website in a Grafana dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847384/embedding-a-website-in-a-grafana-dashboard)

So, Anyone have any idea on this, please help me.

And, if you need more information about this, let me know.

**Thanks** in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Today Azure Data Explorer dashboards doesn't support iframe embedding, thus this is not possible.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you are saying: "In Azure Data Explorer, we can't embed iframe". 
But, mine question is other way around. If I reframe my question, that is, Can we embed any url(in our case Azure data Explorer dashboard share url) in Grafana Dashboard as Iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the native Garfana connector to ADX https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/grafana?

Should be better than to embed one dashboard tech in the other.

Can you share why you are trying to do this vs using the built-in Grafana support for ADX?